# Trying to create a string with template values and unit test that the template is processing correctly

Tags: perl, unit-testing, template-toolkit

I am trying to create a test file that inputs template values into a string using the template toolkit but I don't know what check/tests to include to make sure the template toolkit is processing the string correctly. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use lib ('./t/lib/');

use strict;
use warnings;

use Template;

use Test::More tests => 1;



# options/configuration for template
 my $config = {
     #PRE_PROCESS => 1, # means the templates processed can use the same global vars defined earlier
     #INTERPOLATE => 1,
     #EVAL_PERL => 1,
     RELATIVE => 1,
     OUTPUT_PATH => './out',

 };

my $template = Template->new($config);

# input string
my $text = "This is string number [%num%] ."; 

# template placeholder variables
my $vars = {
     num => "one",
 };


# processes imput string and inserts placeholder values 
my $create_temp = $template->process(\$text, $vars)
    || die "Template process failed: ", $template->error(), "\n";


#is(($template->process(\$text, $vars)), '1' , 'The template is processing correctly');

# If process method is executed successfully it should have a return value of 1
diag($template->process(\$text, $vars));
```

The diag function returns a value of 1, which from the documentation means that the string has been processed  sucessfully, but I have been trying check what the stdout is so I can see the output string but I can get it to print. I have tried writing the stdout to a file from the terminal command but nothing appears in the file. I can write the stderr to a file though.
I have also been trying different configuration for the template as seen in the code below. Is it not working because I am not running any tests, or am I using the Template Toolkit in the wrong way?

If there is any other required information to needed to answer this question just comment below.

Comment: You're describing the problem a bit over-complicated I think. While it's good to give background, the real problem gets lost. I think you're asking how to check if Template creates the right output, so that's what I answered. Basically you want to test if your templates work?

Comment: Yes. haha. Sorry. I was trying to be detailed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer assumes that the `$template->process` statement is really in your production code, and not in the unit test, and shows how to do it if you cannot just tell it to redirect the output into a variable, [like Dave shows in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36650560/1331451).

You can use [Test::Output](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Output) to check `STDOUT`.

```
use Test::Output;

stdout_is { $template->process( \$text, $vars ) } q{This is string number one .},
    q{Template generates the correct output};
```

---

An alternative could be [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) and a two-step test.

```
use Capture::Tiny 'capture_stdout';

my $output = capture_stdout {
    ok $template->process( \$text, $vars ), q{Template processes successfully};
};
is $output, q{This is string number one .}, q{... and the output is correct};
```

---

Note that both solutions will eat the output, so it also doesn't mess with your terminal (it cannot mess with the TAP, as the Test::Harness only looks at `STDOUT`).

Answer (score 4):

Your main problem here is that `process()` sends its output to STDOUT and you're not capturing it. So you're not seeing the expanded output anythere.

The `process()` method takes an optional third argument which can take all sorts of useful values. You probably want to pass it a reference to an empty scalar variable, which then gets filled with the expanded template.

```
$template->process(\$text, $vars, \$output);
is($output, $expected_output);
```

But it's worth noting that the TT distribution includes [Template::Test](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Test), which you'll probably find very useful.

Comment: I was not aware of Template::Test. Very useful. :)

Comment: And I had forgotten about it. But I was sure that something like that **must** exist :-)

Comment: Now I'm thinking how we can use it at $work to get more kind-of frontend coverage. Yay. :) Also added a disclaimer to my answer to make it a bit more different from yours.

Comment: The [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Test#HISTORY) for Template::Test say that it became mostly redundant with the advent of Test::More. Personally, I don't like how you have to embed the tests for `test_expect()` in a specially-formatted file or `__DATA__` block.